# How to disable online in Dark Souls 1 while keeping Steam online?

Tags: steam, mods, dark-souls

I need to disable Dark Souls 1 online features. Usually people do it by putting the whole Steam offline, but I need Steam to be online.

As far as I know there is [PvPWatchdog](https://www.nexusmods.com/darksouls/mods/849/?) mod, which allows you to kick invaders by pressing F1. So it feels like what I want is possible (I need the same but fast and automatic, so player invasions doesn't interfere with my gameplay at all).

P.S. To be super exact:

What I need:

1. To be a human without risk of a player invasion.
2. To be able to receive steam-messages from friends, while I'm playing DS1.
3. Steam should keep tracking my play hours in DS1.

What I don't care about:

1. All other DS1 online features. Like co-op PvE or soap-stone messages. If they are disabled as well I don't care. If they stay while invasions are disabled i'm fine with it.
2. NPC invasions. They may stay or they may never happen - i don't care.

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?rlz=1C1GGRV_deDE757DE757&q=dark+souls+1+offline&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjn-_0pa7WAhUJfhoKHaqnBm8QvwUIIygA&biw=1920&bih=1070 so many links on google regarding this topic

Comment: Basically, the hollow form is the games "offline" mode ... is there any reason why you want to be human? There are literally no penalties for playing hollow.

Comment: @YUNOWORK just for completeness, there are a few things that can only be done in human form: Kindling a bonfire and summoning. Some events also require a human form.

Comment: @YUNOWORK, first of all, to look good. Secondly, to don't waste time (on killing myself) and humanity each time I kindle a bonfire.

Comment: Just a caveat, DS1 plays very, VERY poorly on the PC with mouse and keyboard.  The mouse control is total garbage, and there are no good ways to deal with that.  If this frustrates you, DS2 is a MUCH better port.  I've played through DS2 about 6 times.

Answer (score 4):

Well apparently Dark Souls goes through Steam for multiplayer because of how it used to use GFWL. According to [this post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/211420/discussions/0/622954302100677163/#c622954302102484482), you would need to block port 3074 to block off multiplayer.

---

A pretty simple and generic way to do that is to open the Windows firewall UI (or any other firewall you have), add the executable and deny it all connections. Do it for both inbound and outbound connections and the game just won't be able to use the internet.

Comment: +1 I've done this for other games in Steam (not DS specifically though) and it works like a charm.

Comment: Very nice idea, but it doesn't work for some reason. I've checked and it works with Steam application itself (I can start it in offline mode only), it also works with another game of my (in steam), but DS1 ignores it for some reason. DS doesn't say that it will start in offline mode and I still can see player messages, for example.

Comment: That's surprising! I suppose you could find and block the ports DS1/Steam uses for that. Surely PvPWatchdog has that information.

Comment: Strange, but after like half an hour the game went offline, now I don't see any player messages and the game shows warning about offline mode. Hope it will stay this way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately both options doesn't quite work, so I have to uncheck this answer with hope that someone will propose something else. If I deny all connections the steam has a stupid conflict and wouldn't count number of hours spent in the game (just like if I would turn steam offline). If I deny 3074 TPC&UDP port only I still can have player invasions.